# Connect to SQL Server via Hamachi VPN - SSMS works, Node doesn't

Tags: node.js, sql-server, vpn, hamachi

I can connect fine with SQL Server Management Studio, but not with Node.

I am using the `mssql` npm package.

Here's the node connection.

```js
db: {
    server: "123.456.789.255\\WEBSQL",
    database: "db_name",
    user: "user",
    password: "pass"
}
```

I am getting a `ETIMEOUT` error.

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 123.456.789.255\\WEBSQL in 15000ms
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this fixed the problem.

```js
options: {
    encrypt: false,
},
```